# Convert Long and Lat to Northings / Eastings in PHP

Tags: php, latitude-longitude

I need to convert Longitude and Latitude to Northings / Eastings via a PHP function. Has anyone come across one? I found this one:

https://gist.github.com/duedal/840476

but I tested the result of convertLatLngToUtm() function against http://www.gridreferencefinder.com/ and the two results were different so I'm guessing it's not working / correct.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [proj4php](https://github.com/proj4php/proj4php). It should provide any kind of coordinate transformation.